# How to control GtkScales with Python?

Tags: python, quickly, glade

I want to add GtkScales in a Quickly application and control it with Python to adjust Brightness via `xrandr`. We have already made the code via raw Python [here](https://github.com/lordamit/Brightness) and would like to do this via Quickly to have things like PPA easily.

Comment: What are sliders? I don't know any GTK widget called that.

Comment: @Timo What are these things called? http://lordamit.github.io/Brightness/assets/img/screenshot-1.png

Comment: That's a GtkScale, it should be available in Glade in your `Control and Display` catalog. C docs are here: https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.6/GtkScale.html